# How did WindowsPhone projects to load resource by default?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I like the way that Windows Phone projects load the default resources like these ones:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="PhoneApp4.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">
    ...
```

PhoneFontFamilyNormal, PhoneFontSizeNormal, PhoneForegroundBrush. Because I'm creating many libraries for WPF and all of them contains a common library, and I was thinking when loads that library, load by default also my style resources.

How can I implement this way?

By the way, I'm working with WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as nobody answered I will try to help you..

You can define a resource in your App.xaml for all your application uses (I suppose you already knew about it), Sample:

```
xmlns:win="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

and

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <win:Double x:Key="MyBigFontStyle">186.667</win:Double>
        <!-- .... -->
```

and.. Pages in my application:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage x:Class="Project.Page"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
        xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
        FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
        FontSize="{StaticResource MyBigFontStyle}"
<!-- .... -->
```

And with that all texts are giants because of a dependency property changed.
Now technically speaking ..

There are dependency properties on the microsoft world, where their values ​​are always inherited from parent components.
Example: (DataContext, FontFamily, FontSize, etc.)
This only happens when they are not explicit (Is there no one modifying, interacting with them, among other exceptions).

Although I never sought the respect of how to create one of them or how they work ..
You can override the default value to extend to all components of your application.
For Windows Phone, I used the following feature:

```
    public App()
    {
        // Global handler for uncaught exceptions.
        UnhandledException += Application_UnhandledException;

        // Standard Silverlight initialization
        InitializeComponent();

        // Phone-specific initialization
        InitializePhoneApplication();

        var myNewBrush = new SolidColorBrush(new Color { B = 255, A = 255, R = 88, G = 255 });
        this.Resources.Remove("PhoneAccentBrush");
        this.Resources.Add("PhoneAccentBrush", myNewBrush);

        // Other code that might be here already...
    }
```

This can be done with any standard resources. 
This is done this way because there are no DynamicResources as the WPF

NOTE: How is a StaticResource, if you change it in the middle of running your application, your changes are not propagated.

Sorry for poor English, do not know if that's exactly what you wanted to know, but I have helped in something.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add resources inside your library itself.

Example:

If you have a custom control called MyControl, you can define the resources as shown below.

```
public class MyControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {

       var myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
       this.Resources.Add("MyBrush", myBrush);
    }
}
```

Then once you add the reference to your dll in a WPF project, you will get that resource available through out your control.

Example:

```
<my:MyControl Foreground="MyBrush">
```

Comment: Your solution will not work. Set in Foreground="{StaticResource MyBrush}". Another problem is that at design time, the component will not see. The ideal is to define resources in xaml code.